# Mapstruct - Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping property

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using mapstruct to map from one DTO to another. I have multiple default methods , but 2 of them with a return value of String and that uses the same class as the input parameter gives me "Ambiguous mapping methods using java Mapstruct" error. I am adding the relevant parts of the code here:

```
@Mappings({
     @Mapping(source = "programInstance", target = "title", qualifiedByName = "title"),
     @Mapping(source = "programInstance", target = "seriesName", qualifiedByName = "seriesName"),
     @Mapping(source = "programInstance", target = "season", qualifiedByName = "season"),
     @Mapping(source = "programInstance", target = "epNumber", qualifiedByName = "epNumber"),
 })
 DTO1 mapDTOs (DTO2 dto2);

  @Named("title")
default String mapTitle(Program programInstance) {
    Optional<String> title = Utils.getObject(() -> programInstance.getTitle().getDescriptions().get(0).getValue());
    if (title.isPresent())
        return title.get();
    return null;
}
@Named("seriesName")
default String mapSeriesName(Program programInstance) {
    Optional<String> seriesName = Utils.getObject(() -> programInstance.get(0).getProgram().getTitle().getDescriptions().get(0).getValue());
    if (seriesName.isPresent())
        return seriesName.get();
    return null;
}
 @Named("season")
default Integer mapSeasonNumber(Program programInstance) {
    Optional<Integer> season = Utils.getObject(() -> programInstance.get(0).getSeasonOf().get(0).getOrderNo());
    if (season.isPresent())
        return season.get();
    return null;
}

@Named("epNumber")
default Integer mapEpNumber(Program programInstance) {
    Optional<Integer> epNumber = Utils.getObject(() -> programInstance.getEpOf().get(0).getOrderNo());
    if (epNumber.isPresent())
        return epNumber.get();
    return null;
}
```

The error is

> Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping property "Program
>   programInstance" to java.lang.String: java.lang.String mapTitle(),
>   java.lang.String mapSeriesName().

Comment: Are you sure that you are using `org.mapstruct.Named` and not some other one?

Comment: @Filip Yes I am using org.mapstruct.Named

Comment: Just verified your example on our 1.3 code base.. It works

Comment: but.. I also spotted the name of the method deviates.. `mapSeriesName`.. Your example has a signature `mapSeriesName1 `.. Do you by any chance point to a used mapper? Are there more methods that carry the same `@Named`?

Comment: sjaak:  that was a type, sorry, edited the code. My version was 1.2, tried changing to 1.3 now - the error still exists.. Yes, I have more @Named methods that carry the same source Program..

Comment: edited code to add the other methods that use Program as the source

Comment: just out of curiosity, if you add ignore=true to the 2 String mappings.. does MapStruct complain about the Integer mappings as well?

Comment: Is there anyway (e.g. gist) that you can share the DTO's as well. I can give it a shot tomorrow..

Comment: Yes, it does complain about the Integer mappings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188239/discussion-between-ljs-and-sjaak).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I checked your example.. The problem is that the fields you try to target are of type String.

So:

```
public class IvpVodOfferStatusDTO {

    private String seasonNumber;
    private String episodeNumber;
}
```

MapStruct tries to match this with the signature you provide:

```
 @Named("season")
default Integer mapSeasonNumber(Program programInstance) {
    Optional<Integer> season = Utils.getObject(() -> programInstance.get(0).getSeasonOf().get(0).getOrderNo());
    if (season.isPresent())
        return season.get();
    return null;
}

@Named("epNumber")
default Integer mapEpNumber(Program programInstance) {
    Optional<Integer> epNumber = Utils.getObject(() -> programInstance.getEpOf().get(0).getOrderNo());
    if (epNumber.isPresent())
        return epNumber.get();
    return null;
}
```

MapStruct has a predefined order of attempts:

1. User provided Mapping method
2. Direct (types source -target are the same)
3. Mapping method (built-in)
4. Type conversion

If this all fails MapStruct tries to do a number of 2 step approaches:

5. mapping method - mapping method
6. mapping method - type conversion
7. type conversion - mapping method

At 6. it finds 2 qualifying methods (`Program` to `String`). It's probably an error in MapStruct that it selects methods that do not qualify (need to check whether this is intentional) by the `@Named`. Otherwise, I'll write an issue.

The most easy solution is: adapt the target:

```
public class IvpVodOfferStatusDTO {

    private Integer seasonNumber;
    private Integer episodeNumber;
}
```

What is probably what you intend (I guess).. Otherwise you could change the signature not to return an `Integer` but a `String`

Answer (score 4):

Even if the data types are matching, this could happen if the name given at qualifiedByName is not defined in as a bean instance

Because without a matching @Named qualifier, the injector would not know which bean to bind to which variable

```
@Mapping( source = "firstName", target = "passenger.firstName", qualifiedByName = "mapFirstName" )
public abstract Passenger mapPassenger( Traveller traveller );

@Named( "mapFirstName" )
String mapFirstName( String firstName)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same issue and observed that, there was same method inherited by my mapper class using @Mapper(uses = {BaseMapper.class}) and using extends BaseMapper.
Removing extends solved the problem for me.
So, you can look for method received by custom mapper through multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

`Ambiguous mapping methods` can also happen if a `@Named("name")` method annotation is duplicated with the same `"name"`:  They need to be unique across `@Named` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Also note you may get this if you have cyclic dependency:

```
ObjectA -> ObjectB -> ObjectA -> ObjectB
```

It will be reported as an ambiguous entry most of the time. The solution is to not refer to Object A in ObjectB.